# Resize image slider to the current image's aspect ratio in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, slide

I made this fully working image slider, and the only thing I want it to do now is resize its height to the current image's aspect ratio. I wrote a loop that calculates aspect ratio for every image in the slider, the only problem is that, when executed, the loop returns all the values at once, when I only need it to give me one after another value for `adjustedHeight` each click.

I tried putting `i++` inside the loop, pushing all values into an array, which requires another loop to iterate between the array's values, but all of that just feels more complicated than it needs.

```
<div class="slider-images">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1280x720.png">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1280x720.png">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1280x960.png">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1280x720.png">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1280x720.png">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1280x720.png">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1280x720.png">
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
const images = document.querySelector('.slider-images');
const image = document.querySelectorAll('.slider-images img');

var i;

function slideRight() {
    //...

    for (i = 0; i < image.length; i++) { // Calculates aspect ratio
        const allImagesWidth = image[i].naturalWidth, 
            allImagesHeight = image[i].naturalHeight;
        const aspectRatio = allImagesWidth / allImagesHeight;
        adjustedHeight = Math.round(slideWidth / aspectRatio); // Final slider height required for a current shown image
    }

    images.style.height = adjustedHeight + 'px'; // Dynamically should add respective height calculated in the loop above

    //...

}
document.querySelector('.slide-right').addEventListener('click', slideRight, false);
```

CSS

```
.slider-images {
    display: flex;
    transition: .5s all cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
    max-width: 200%;
    max-height: 512px;
}

.slider-images img {
    width: 50%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: you don't need to do that, the container adjust his height according the highest contained visible image. you can use only CSS with img{width: 100% ; height: auto}

Comment: @Sim1-81 I know that, but currently images get cropped from the sides if there's a different aspect ratio image in the slide, and I want to keep 100% of the image visible by resizing the container that the images rest in. The images automatically resize to the `slider-images` container until they hit the max width of the container, when they start to crop vertically. I will include CSS of those elements just in case.

Comment: if images are cropped there is a parent element which has overflow:hidden, if so try to remove that line of css, otherwhise you have to loop images on document ready to store into an array the dimension of any image, then when you slide, you can pick from that array the height of current image and apply it to slider. Add some transition to container  to smooth animation. Then if you move out the image loop from slideRight() function and put it in a separate function you can call this other function to store dimension at document.ready() and in window.resize()  to add responsive behavior

Comment: obviously to do what explained above you have to know the index of the next image that has to be shown

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved, works and resizes vertically as I wanted. Just needed to move the loop above the `slideRight` function, set new empty array variable `imageArray`, `push` everything from the loop to that array, and then set the style in the function to read from that array and change width based on already existed variable `position = 0` used for the slider to work.

Also made adjustments in styles, removed `max-height` from `.slider-images`, and set `.slider-images img` to `max-height: unset;`, in case you have your `img` set to `max-height: 100%;` by default.

```
var position = 0;
var index = 0;
var imageArray = [];

//...

for (index; index < image.length; index++) {
    const allImagesWidth = image[index].naturalWidth, 
        allImagesHeight = image[index].naturalHeight;
    const aspectRatio = allImagesWidth / allImagesHeight;
    var adjustedHeight = slideWidth / aspectRatio;

    imageArray.push(adjustedHeight++);
}

images.style.height = imageArray[position] + 'px';

function slideRight() {
    position--;
    images.style.height = imageArray[position] + 'px';
    if (position == -1) {
        position = imageCount - 1;
    }

    images.style.transform = 'translateX(' + -(slideWidth * position) + 'px)';
}   

// ...

document.querySelector('.slide-right').addEventListener('click', slideRight, false);
```